# Is QuartzDesk a suitable tool for monitoring Quartz jobs in a Spring Boot application with Elasticsearch log integration?

Tags: quartz-scheduler

I'm working on a Spring Boot application that relies heavily on Quartz for job scheduling. I also have Elasticsearch integrated into my application for logging purposes. I'm currently exploring options for monitoring and managing Quartz jobs effectively.

Any advice or experiences shared would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I came across QuartzDesk, which seems to offer a comprehensive solution for Quartz job monitoring. However, I'm not sure if it's the right fit for my specific setup where I'm using Elasticsearch for log integration.

I'd like to know if anyone has experience using QuartzDesk in a similar environment and can share their insights. Specifically, I have the following questions:

1. Is QuartzDesk a suitable tool for monitoring Quartz jobs in a Spring Boot application?
2. Are there any challenges or considerations I should be aware of when using QuartzDesk in this setup?
3. Are there alternative tools or approaches that might be better suited for monitoring Quartz jobs in a Spring Boot application with Elasticsearch integration?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, QuartzDesk can manage and monitor Quartz jobs in all types of Java applications. There are no major challenges and considerations we are aware of. To use QuartzDesk, in general you need to do these steps:

1. Add quartzdesk-api.jar to your Quartz-based application and make sure this JAR is on the classpath of the classloader that loads the Quartz API JAR (for webapps, you typically add quartzdesk-api.jar to WEB-INF/lib).
2. Install QuartzDesk JVM Agent on the JVM that powers your Quartz-based application. There is an install doc for this.
3. Install QuartzDesk Webapp that provides the GUI for the QuartzDesk platform. Again, there is an install doc for this.

*Note: I am a bit biased here as I am the principal architect of QuartzDesk. If you need any help, please reach out to us.*